# Two Java classes in parallel packages

Tags: java, package

I have two classes in two parallel packages.

```
me.jayaneetha.testapp.controller.MainController
```

and

```
me.jayaneetha.testapp.util.FileManager
```

When I import `FileManager` Class from the `MainController` Class, it gives the error "**Cannot resolve symbol**"

What might be the problem for this? and a solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [mcve] - it'll make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: You have to import the whole package: `import me.jayaneetha.testapp.util.FileManager;` and **not** only `import util.FileManager;`

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to load the `FileManager` class from the `me.jayaneetha.testapp.controller` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you encounter a situation where you have two libraries containing Java classes with the same name, you need to distinguish one from the other by using its full package name.  In your case, I will assume that the following two packages *both* contain a class called `FileManager`:

```
me.jayaneetha.testapp.controller
me.jayaneetha.testapp.util
```

Assuming you have the following import statement in your code:

```
import me.jayaneetha.testapp.util.FileManager;
```

This means that you can use `FileManager` in your code freely, and furthermore that the compiler will always resolve this class to the package `me.jayaneetha.testapp.util.FileManager`.  If you want to *also* use the `FileManager` class from the `me.jayaneetha.testapp.controller` package, then you will have to refer to its full package name, i.e.

```
me.jayaneetha.testapp.controller.FileManager
```

This is how two Java classes with the same name can happily coexist in a single source file.  If my answer doesn't directly get every detail right about your setup, hopefully it points you in the right direction towards understanding what is happening.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please have some mercy on me, thanks.  My answer is the correct way to resolve duplicate class names, i.e. using the full domain name.

Comment: Actually it was me :) I misunderstood the question, then I realized that and removed my downvote. Sorry Jon.